# Is it possible to convert Ethereum merkle patricia trie to [{address: balance}, {address: balance}, {address: balance}... ]?

Tags: addresses, merkle-patricia-tries

From Merkle Patiricia Trie, seems to be difficult to get all keys, so the only way to make [{address: balance}, {address: balance}, {address: balance}... ]  for all accounts (including contracts), need to watch when function put called ?

Comment: Are you trying to do this inside a contract, or in some other way?

Comment: trying in go-ethereum. would like to just make the list like genesis_block does